# BATCH: "!" OPERATOR in IF-ELSE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file

I need some help. How can I define **!a!** in a MySQL query? Since I got some error result.

```
  setlocal enableextensions 
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

  if !a! EQU !b! (%sql_PATH%\mysql -uroot -e "DROP DATABASE '!a!';")
```

the output is

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax
>       : check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
>       version for the right sytax to use near ''sample
>       sample_1
>       sample_2
>       '' at line 1

my full code

```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableextensions 
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

  set sql_PATH=C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin
  set sql_DIR=C:\Users\neca\Desktop\db_test\databases\db_name
  set "dbUser=root"
  set "dbPass="

  set LF=^
  %empty line%
  %empty line%

  cd %sql_DIR%
  FOR /D %%b IN (*) DO %sql_PATH%\mysql -u%dbUser% -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %%b;" && set "b=!b!%%b!LF!" 

  echo !b!

  cd %sql_PATH%
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
    %sql_PATH%\mysql -u%dbUser% -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%';" 
    ^| findstr /l /v /c:"Database" /c:"information_schema"
`) do (set "a=!a!%%a!LF!")

  echo !a!


  if !a! EQU !b! (%sql_PATH%\mysql -uroot -e "DROP DATABASE !a!;")

  pause
```

Comment: Are you using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`? Without that enabled the `!variable!` syntax doesn't work. FYI, the regular syntax is `%variable%`. If this doesn't solve your problem it would probably help to see more of your script.

Comment: yes i already set it sir. @JamesAdkison

Comment: Well, the variable expansion should be working. I tested `if !a! EQU !b! (echo %sql_PATH%\mysql -uroot -e "DROP DATABASE '!a!';")` and got `\mysql -uroot -e "DROP DATABASE 't';"` so could the problem be with your SQL command and not the batch script? For example, does it work if you replace `!a!` with the hard coded database name?

Comment: thats my full code sir @JamesAdkison

Comment: I don't have *MySQL* installed so I cannot test further. However, the syntax from the documentation for *MySQL 13.1.13* shows this as the syntax `DROP {DATABASE | SCHEMA} [IF EXISTS] db_name`. So perhaps you don't need the single quotes. does `%sql_PATH%\mysql -uroot -e "DROP DATABASE !a!;"` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the batch syntax or delayed expansion not working. Your problem is that the content of the variable is a line feed separated list of databases, but the `DROP DATABASE` command will only accept one database name. You need to iterate over the list of databases to delete and emit a `DROP` command for each one.